# Bash script does not exit in loop

Tags: bash

I have run at below script in HP/UX and get that output:

```
Exiting #1
Exiting #2
```

But I expect that output:

```
Exiting #1
```

Script file:

```
data="aaa; bbb; ccc"

echo $data | while IFS=';' read -ra array; do
    echo "Exiting #1"
    exit -1
done


echo "Exiting #2"

exit 0
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Be aware that -1 is not a valid exit status for a process; it must be a non-negative value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the pipe, the command in the loop run in a subshell. When you call exit, only the subshell is terminated, and not the parent process.

You can overcome this by using `shopt -s lastpipe`, by using process substitution

```
while IFS=';' read -ra array; do
    echo "Exiting #1"
    exit -1
done < <(echo "$data")
```

or by using a here-string

```
while IFS=';' read -ra array; do
    echo "Exiting #1"
    exit -1
done <<< "$data"
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `exit -1` inside the loop, it only exits the subprocess that was created due the pipe. Re-write it to use here-string:

```
 while IFS=';' read -ra array; do
    echo "Exiting #1"
    exit -1
done <<< ${data}
```

Now, you'll get the expected output.